# Restrict server usage for internal use

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a REST web service using spring MVC which is external-facing.
I would like to restrict access to some REST calls for admin usage and for other servers on the same internal network to call.

So far I can think of the following solutions:

1. Use Spring-Security to restrict a mapping to a subnet using "hasIpAddress" access
2. Separate the sensitive REST calls into their own controller and Write an AOP pointcut which reads the HttpServletRequest for the IP address and check against a whitelist

I'm not fond of either solution. (1) doesn't give me enough flexibility, I may be on several subnets, and may only want to open up an IP range. (2) Gives me nearly exactly what I want but it seems hacky, there must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(2) why do you not want to use the "standard" annotations like @PreAuthrize. You can put them at the methods, so you do not need to move the sensitive REST methods to an other controller.

Comment: I don't mind moving the sensitive methods into its own controller, that seems to be a logical thing to do regardless of what approach I take. My gripe with spring security is that I cannot have more fine grained control to do a whitelist or IP range

Answer (score 0):

The way I approached this problem was to have a user login and store their login ID in the session. Then, each type a new request comes in, you check that user's credentials to make sure they have authority to perform that function and are still logged in.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a reverse proxy such as Apache the simplest solution would be to handle this there.

In Spring Security you would create a subclass of `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` which contains your IP-related logic and authenticates the request as principal with a `ROLE_ADMIN`.