# Restricting web service access to internal IP addresses

Tags: java, web-services, security

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070873/restrict-server-usage-for-internal-use) I have some Jersey web services I would like to restrict for internal office use. Is it secure enough to check IP addresses using the HttpServletRequest? Specifically, are there cases where the value returned by request.getRemoteAddress() cannot be trusted? My code is something like this:

```
    @POST
    @Path("update")
    public Response updateCityInfo(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        String remoteAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
        if (!remoteAddress.startsWith("10.10")) {
            return Response.status(Status.FORBIDDEN).build();
        }
        ...
```

I'm not concerned with security so much, I just want anyone from within a certain network to be able to access this endpoint.

Comment: there seems to be no problem with this check. probably a better place would be at the Load balancer level which will filter out all the external IP addresses.

Comment: There's no load balancer, it's just for Dev and QA servers, that will be called from someones box to do some config reloading. I just want to make sure it's not called from anyone outside our local network.

Comment: Even if there is no load balancer then there must be some firewall behind all of your servers that can restrict access to external IP's .  Also you can configure apache to block IPs, my main concern is that your application should only do the required stuff( authentication/autorization/roles/privileges etc) and other business related stuff), blocking and unblocking are Infra based service which your application should not take care of.

Comment: ya, agree, but the other thing is I only want to restrict it for a few of these services, not to the the others.

Comment: I guess your every service will have some unique/different URL, so just allow access based on the service URL.

Answer (score 0):

That might work.  However there are some caveats.  For starters, if you are behind a loadbalancer/proxy, then the remoteAddress will likely be that of the proxy and not of the client who originated the request.  Since loadbalancers are generally inside of your firewall, they will probably have a 10.* address.

This seems like something that should be handled at the firewall level and not at the application level.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering in-coming request from external address at the network level can easily prevent your application from being spoofed. But this does not mean that your application is not doing any thing in terms of security. your application should have a proper authentication and authorization mechanism.

Comment: I see your point, and agree for 99% of the cases, but this is a stateless service that I'd like to just hit via a URL, and have it reload some config data. We have it exposed via JMX, but it's needed  frequent enough, that I'd just like to hit it from a curl, or browser.

Comment: whatever ips(External) you want to hit with, you need to ensure that these IP's are whitelisted at your end